# Static files return Internal Server Error

Tags: iis, web-applications, internal-server-error, .net-framework-version, static-files

I hosted a site called Paris on an IIS-server (Windows Server 2019), which have have 2 web applications

- webParkingQueryApi
- webParkingQueryApp

The file explorer path look like this:

- Paris/ParkingQueryWebApi
- Paris/ParkingQueryWebApp

Both application use the same AppPool, and both are .Net 4.6 Framework applications (one web API and one Web application).

**AppPool**: Name: Paris | Managed Pipeline: Integrated | .NET CLR version : 4.0 | Identity : {a service account in the AD}

**Authentication** Paris : anonymous. ParkingQueryWebApp : basic.

**Problem:** When I open webParkingQueryApp in browser all static files return "Internal Server Error".

Both applications work fine in my development server, but not in production.

I added permissions to the Service Account, DefaultAppPool, and Users so they can read, write and modify the Paris directory.

The Event Viewer throws an security warning when I refresh the site. It says : "A privileged service was called.", and it mentions Process Name:    C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe. The security Id is my Windows account that I use to log into production.

**EDIT**

After I activated "Failed Request Tracing Rules" in IIS-manager and looked in the log files I found this error:

```
<RenderingInfo Culture="sv-SE">
  <Opcode>MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">AUTHENTICATE_REQUEST</freb:Description>
  <freb:Description Data="ErrorCode">Either a required impersonation level was not provided, or the provided impersonation level is invalid.
 (0x80070542)</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
```

**EDIT 2022-02-04**

The static files return this information:

> HTTP Error 500.0 | Module: IIS Web Core | Notification:
> AuthenticateRequest | Handler: StaticFile | Error Code:0x80070542 |
> Logon method: basic | Logon user: {my Windows account}.

Comment: Have you tried accessing those static resources individually by URL? What status codes and error messages do they return? What is the extension of these static files? You can check to see if there are these suffixes in the MIMe Type of IIS and if there are handlers in the Handler Mapping.

Comment: Yes, there are all kinds of files, png, js, asp. These files types are in list of MIME types and have the value inherited. I am not sure what to look for in the Handler Mapping, there are plenty of items in that list.

Comment: So what's the status code and sub status code of these static files?